# SIM800l Ardunio Mini 5V 16Mhz Mega328 (new to this) SMS messaging

Tags: arduino, sms

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
//SIM800 TX is connected to Arduino D8
#define SIM800_TX_PIN 8

//SIM800 RX is connected to Arduino D7
#define SIM800_RX_PIN 7

//Create software serial object to communicate with SIM800
SoftwareSerial serialSIM800(SIM800_TX_PIN,SIM800_RX_PIN);

void setup() {
//Begin serial comunication with Arduino and Arduino IDE (Serial Monitor)
Serial.begin(9600);
while(!Serial);

//Being serial communication with Arduino and SIM800
serialSIM800.begin(9600);

Serial.println("Setup Complete!");

//serialSIM800.println("AT+CSPN?\r\n");
//serialSIM800.println("AT+EXUNSOL=\"SQ\",1\r\n");
//serialSIM800.println("AT");

//delay(1000);

//Send SMS
Serial.println("Sending Text...");
delay(1000);
serialSIM800.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");
serialSIM800.print("AT+CMGS=\"0781xxxxxxx\"\r");
delay(200);
//Send SMS content
serialSIM800.print("TEST");
serialSIM800.print("\r");
delay(500);
//Send Ctrl+Z / ESC to denote SMS message is complete
serialSIM800.print((char)26);
delay(100);
serialSIM800.println();
delay(500);
Serial.println("SMS Sent!");
delay(500);
}
void loop() {
//Read SIM800 output (if available) and print it in Arduino IDE Serial Monitor
if(serialSIM800.available()){
Serial.write(serialSIM800.read());

}
//Read Arduino IDE Serial Monitor inputs (if available) and send them to SIM800
if(Serial.available()){
serialSIM800.write(Serial.read()); 

}
}
```

The code above when uploaded runs generate no errors but no SMS received.

serial mode displays the following;-

Setup Complete!
Sending Text...
SMS Sent!
AT+CMGF=1
AT+CMGS="0781xxxxxxx"

OK
TEST

> Call Ready

obviously I send the text to my mobile that's available tried the country code option also. I haven't been able to find anything that helps online as yet and was hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found the answer, the code is fine.

Checked the power at 4.1V which is fine
So with the above code I needed to make sure that I pressed and held the Reset button on the mini board until the sim800L led went from fast flashing to slow flashing, then the text was generated and sent to the number programmed.

As I am new to this, I couldn't find clear guidance anywhere that explained this, so was scratching my head a little.

Now to the next step.